# iOS in-app subscription / auto-renewable subscription conversion

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm trying to write an app that has two auto-renewable subscriptions: one regular, one premium.  Suppose a user has the regular subscription, is there a way to convert it to a premium subscription and have it be auto-renewable?

Your response is very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Apple manages much of an Auto-Renewable subscription once it has begun, you have limited control over it. You can always have a user buy a new subscription to your premium account, but I don't think you can force a user to stop auto-renewing on the regular account without removing it from iTunes Connect (or asking them to manually cancel it themselves).